# How can I find the max of every 5 elements of an array in C

Tags: c

So I need to write a program which takes (by user input) a integer array of 100 elements and finds the max of every 5 elements and writes them in a new array and adds the rest of the numbers to another array.

So an example would be:
original array (array1): 1,23,6,7,16,19,24,56,99,43 ...

soo it will take the first 5 elements: 1,23,6,7,16 and find the max value (23) and add it to the new array 
then the next 5 : 19,24,56,99,43 find their max (99) and add it to the other array and so on until it reaches the last number.

second array (array2): 23,99 
third array (array3): 1,6,7,16,19,24,56,43

I've tried everything, but i can only get either the Max number in the WHOLE array or the max number of the FIRST 5 elements.

This is how my program should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int array1[100];
int array2[100];
int size;

int main() {
            printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
            scanf("%d", &size);
            if (size > 100) {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("\nEnter %d numbers: \n", size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
            }
            printf("\nEntered array: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                printf("%d, ", array1[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");

// the code for the max numbers should be here

            printf("The max values of every 5 elements are: \n");
            for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            printf("%d, ", array2[i]);
            }
}
```

"size2" is the size of the new array.

Comment: To start, write code that, starting at index s, finds the maximum of the elements indexed from s to s+4. Then figure out how to use that code to solve the rest of the problem.

Comment: well @EricPostpischil i tried a few variations of the solve you're suggesting, but they all lead to either crashing or non executable programs, since the "rest of the problem" is exaclty the thing i can't solver

Comment: solve* not solver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int array1[100];
int array2[100];
int array3[100];
int size, size2, size3;

int main() {
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    if (size > 100) {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nEnter %d numbers: \n", size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEntered array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d", array1[i]);
        if(i%5==4) printf("| ");
        else printf(", ");
    }
    printf("\n");

// the code for the max numbers should be here

    size2=0; size3=0;
    int maxvalue_index=0;
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
      if(array1[i]>array1[maxvalue_index]) maxvalue_index=i;
      if(i%5==4 || i==size-1){
        array2[size2]=array1[maxvalue_index];
        size2++;
        for(int j=i-(i%5); j<=i ; j++){
          if(array1[j]==array1[maxvalue_index]) continue;
          array3[size3]=array1[j];
          size3++;
        }
        maxvalue_index=i+1;
      }
    }
    printf("The max values of every 5 elements are: \n");
    for(int i=0;i<size2;i++) printf("%d ",array2[i]);
    printf("\nArray3\n");
    for(int i=0;i<size3;i++) printf("%d ",array3[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Try this, It will work for non 5*n lengths
Let me know if there is any error :)

Comment: This works exactly as i need it, thank you very much kind man.

Answer (score 0):

The function below finds the maximum of elements in the array from `start` to `end` exclusive.

```
int findmax(int *const arr, const size_t len, const size_t begin, size_t end) {
        int res = arr[begin];
        end = (len < end) ? len : end;

        for (int i = begin+1; i < end; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > res)
                        res = arr[i];
        }

        return res;
}
```

Define this function before your `main`, then call it for every five elements; the maximum of the first five elements is `findmax(array1, size1, 0, 5)`, for the next
five it would be `findmax(array1, size1, 5, 10)` and so on and so forth. It shouldn't take that much effort to make a for loop that automates the process.

Comment: i will try it out, but im using VisualStudio and it says that "end" must be a modifiable value

Comment: remove `const` .